# Adwords Editorでのインポートエラー

Tags: google-bigquery

他社が管理していたadwordsの情報をadwords editorでエクスポートしたCSVデータをもらったので、新しく作ったアカウントにインポートしようとすると、「必須のアカウント列がありません」というエラーが出てインポートすることができません。

どなたか解決方法が分かる方はいませんでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。
Adwords editorで現在のアカウントの情報をエクスポートし、その一列目のAccountの列を追加したいファイルの一列目に追加したら無事インポートできました。